# Why do I get "compile_time_choice.S: No such file or directory" when building the blink example?

Tags: pi-pico

I'm roughly following this tutorial but with cygwin instead:
https://shawnhymel.com/2096/how-to-set-up-raspberry-pi-pico-c-c-toolchain-on-windows-with-vs-code/

I use cygwin for another project so I would rather not switch to another GNU tools package.

I have:

- Installed cmake, gcc, make via cygwin
- Installed git via Git for Windows
- Installed rpi pico sdk
- Configured and tested environment variables (looks ok to me)
- Created the makefiles using cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" ..

When I cd into the blink directory and try to make, I eventually get this:

```
Scanning dependencies of target bs2_default
[  0%] Building ASM object pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/boot_stage2/CMakeFiles/bs2_default.dir/compile_time_choice.S.obj
cc1.exe: fatal error: /cygdrive/c/VSARM/picosdk/src/rp2_common/boot_stage2/compile_time_choice.S: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

What am I missing?

---

I've tried this with cmake 3.20.0 and 3.23.2. In between, I deleted the build folder and recreated it. The result was the same in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

I am having similar issues.  I think the problem is that we're calling the arm compiler using the cygwin file path, but the compiler only understands MSDOS paths.  I ended up installing minGW64 and then setting up an alternate universe (ok, just a alternate path) that included minGW64 and excluded Cygwin.